# httpcontext returns user identity as null even if user is logged in, trying to set authenticationfilter for hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire, httpcontext

I'm trying to configure hangfire authentication by only allowing users with admin role to access /hangfire, but when doing so the user in httpcontext is always set as null even thoug the user is logged in.

The HangFireAuthorizationFilter:

```
    public class HangFireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {

        public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
        {
            var httpContextUser = context.GetHttpContext().User;
            var userIsAdmin = httpContextUser.IsInRole(SD.RoleAdmin);
            var userIsAuthenticated = httpContextUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            return userIsAdmin && userIsAuthenticated;
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IDbInitializer dbInitializer)
        {
            app.UseHangfireServer();
            app.UseHangfireDashboard(
                pathMatch: "/hangfire",
                options: new DashboardOptions()
                {
                Authorization = new IDashboardAuthorizationFilter[] {new HangFireAuthorizationFilter(),

                }
            });
            // etc...
        }
```

It seems to work fine in my controllers and views as:

```
@if (User.IsInRole(SD.RoleAdmin))
{
<div style="margin-top:0.5rem" align="center">
    <p>Admin user!</p>
</div>
}
```

works just fine and returns the "Admin user!", but it is not returning the user in the filter and I can't figure out why...

Comment: I want to ask you what is `GetHttpContext()`method in your filter,I can't find it in `DashboardContext`

Comment: According to docs: 
"For ASP.NET Core environments, use the GetHttpContext extension method defined in the Hangfire.AspNetCore package."

Comment: I should thank you though. Your question led me to check the docs more thoroughly leading me to find the solution to my problem :)

Comment: Glad you can solve this problem:)

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by moving these methods

```
            app.UseHangfireServer();
            app.UseHangfireDashboard(
                pathMatch: "/hangfire",
                options: new DashboardOptions()
                {
                Authorization = new IDashboardAuthorizationFilter[] {new HangFireAuthorizationFilter(),

                }
            });
```

after other authentication methods, as stated in the docs... The httpcontext returned the user with relevant info without problems then.